# jQuery – "Read More" span not reappearing after clicking "Read Less"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm setting up a portfolio website with project descriptions that are previewed with an excerpt and reveal the full details upon clicking "Read More." I'm pretty new to jQuery but I got it working so that you click "Read More," the paragraph shows up with a "Close" span at the end, and then you click "Close" and it disappears. The problem is "Read More" doesn't reappear after the paragraph is hidden.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOegJx

```
<div class="project-description">
    <p class="excerpt">Excerpt goes here.</p>
    <span class="read-more open">Read More</span>
    <p class="full hidden">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos. 
   <span class="read-more close">Close</span></p>
</div>


.full {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.open').click(function() {
     $(this).siblings('.full').removeClass('hidden');
     $(this).css('display', 'none');
  })

  $('.close').click(function() {
     $(this).parent('.full').addClass('hidden');
     $(this).parent('.open').css('display', 'block');
  })
});
```

(My site is one-page, so I tried to write the JS in a way that won't open up all of my other project's descriptions, just the one I clicked "Read More" on. Not sure if that affects finding a solution)

Comment: 'open' is not a parent of 'close'.  It's a sibling of one of it's parents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.open is not a parent of .close - so you need to select it as follows:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.open').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you! Still learning all the tree traversal stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Something you've done that is a great thing: you have contained the stuff you'll be working with to a single element. Something that works well is to create a reference to that container el, then use that and create references to the descendant nodes. Note in the following, I don't care which nodes contain what, or are siblings to what -- they're all descendants of your `.project-description`. By creating the references to them within the .each() statement, you can have multiple copies of this on a page that don't crash with each other.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var containerEl = $('.project-description');
  
  containerEl.each(function(){
    var openEl = $(this).find('.open');
    var closeEl = $(this).find('.close');
    var fullEl = $(this).find('.full');

    openEl.click(function() {
       fullEl.removeClass('hidden');
       $(this).css('display', 'none');
    })

    closeEl.click(function() {
       fullEl.addClass('hidden');
       openEl.css('display', 'inline-block');
    })
  
  })
});
```

```css
.full {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

.read-more {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-description">
    <p class="excerpt">Excerpt goes here.</p>
    <span class="read-more open">Read More</span>
    <p class="full hidden">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos. 
   <span class="read-more close">Close</span></p>
</div>
<div class="project-description">
    <p class="excerpt">Second goes here.</p>
    <span class="read-more open">Read More</span>
    <p class="full hidden">Proin eget tortor risus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem.
   <span class="read-more close">Close</span></p>
</div>
<div class="project-description">
    <p class="excerpt">And another goes here.</p>
    <span class="read-more open">Read More</span>
    <p class="full hidden">Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. 
   <span class="read-more close">Close</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Very useful and informative answer. This is exactly what I was looking for, with how it's confined to each of my projects and set up to not interfere with the other ones. Thank you!

Comment: If it worked for you, be sure to upvote. and I'm glad it worked out. You'd already laid the groundwork, by having the elements contained within a DOM node.